# Cannot resolve collation conflict in Union select

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I've got two queries:

First doesn't work:

```
select hotels.TargetCode as TargetCode from hotels
union all 
select DuplicatedObjects.duplicatetargetCode as TargetCode 
from DuplicatedObjects where DuplicatedObjects.objectType=4
```

because I get error:

```
Cannot resolve collation conflict for column 1 in SELECT statement.
```

Second works:

```
select hotels.Code from hotels where hotels.targetcode is not null 
union all 
select DuplicatedObjects.duplicatetargetCode as Code 
from DuplicatedObjects where DuplicatedObjects.objectType=4
```

Structure:

```
Hotels.Code -PK nvarchar(40)
Hotels.TargetCode - nvarchar(100)

DuplicatedObjects.duplicatetargetCode PK nvarchar(100)
```

Comment: What's the relevance of C# here?

Comment: @John Skeet I've corrected it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `sp_help` on both tables. The collation on hotels.TargetCode is different from the collation on `DuplicatedObjects.duplicateTargetCode`, so the DB doesn't know what to do with the resulting `UNION`.

You can force a new collation on one of them to match the other, or put the results into a predefined temp table/table which will have a collation defined already.

**EDIT:** You can override the existing collation using something like...

```
DuplicatedObjects.duplicateTargetCode COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

...in the query. This will use the duplicateTargetCode with the collation `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`. You should choose a collation which matches that of `hotels.TargetCode`.

Answer (score 19):

You need to add the `collation` statement in the select part as well - not only in the where clause - like the following:

```
select a.field1 collate DATABASE_DEFAULT, b.otherfield from table1 a, table2 b 
where a.field1 collate DATABASE_DEFAULT = b.field3
```

Answer (score 4):

Trying to set collation in a query when joining a linked server can still fail with `Incorrect syntax near 'COLLATE'` even though your syntax is correct.

Solution: In Linked Server Properties, set `Use Remote Collation` to False, and enter the desired collation type in `Collation Name` - removes need to force collation in your query.

Comment: This is not recommended without performance testing because it can drastically alter your query plan and lead to much more expensive queries compared to specifying the collation in the query. In one case, something that was taking 2 secs with collation specified in the query took 2 mins when collation was specified on the linked server.

Answer (score 2):

Your collation conflict may go away if you declare the temp table #list as

```
 CREATE TABLE #list
 (
 record_num INT IDENTITY(1,1),
 TempAcctNum NVARCHAR(40) Collate Database_Default,
 TempAcctName NVARCHAR(100) Collate Database_Default,
 TempNumOfCrds SMALLINT,
 TempSys2Acct NVARCHAR(10) Collate Database_Default,
 TempDelType TINYINT,
 TempStatusOfCrd VARCHAR(100) Collate Database_Default,
 TempLastDate VARCHAR(100) Collate Database_Default,
 TempSys2Acct1 NVARCHAR(10) Collate Database_Default,
 TempShrtName NVARCHAR(50) Collate Database_Default,
 TempAdd1 NVARCHAR(200) Collate Database_Default,
 TempAdd2 NVARCHAR(200) Collate Database_Default,
 TempCity NVARCHAR(100) Collate Database_Default,
 TempState NVARCHAR(100) Collate Database_Default,
 TempZipCode NVARCHAR(50) Collate Database_Default,
 TempOpenDate DATETIME,
 TempFax NVARCHAR(50) Collate Database_Default,
 TempUsr1 NVARCHAR(100) Collate Database_Default,
 TempUsr2 NVARCHAR(100) Collate Database_Default,
 TempUsr3 NVARCHAR(100) Collate Database_Default,
 TempUsr4 NVARCHAR(100) Collate Database_Default,
 TempMemo NTEXT,
 TempMail NVARCHAR(100) Collate Database_Default,
 TempNoSys2Status NVARCHAR(50) Collate Database_Default,
 TempDelete BIT,
 TempEdit BIT,
 TempContName VARCHAR(200) Collate Database_Default,
 TempPhone NVARCHAR(50) Collate Database_Default
 )
```

Comment: I think this can be help YOU

Comment: Good solution when using #temp tables 